# Cómo escribir un comando linux que muestre los archivos y directorios vacíos del directorio de trabajo

Tags: linux, shell

- Estoy usando find . -empty, pero muestra la ruta completa de los archivos y directorios. Solo necesito mostrar el nombre del archivo y/o directorio vacío
- Solo debe imprimir el nombre del archivo o directorio, no la ruta completa
- Debe listar también los archivos ocultos

Comment: Estoy usando **find . -empty**, pero muestra la ruta completa de los archivos y directorios. Solo necesito mostrar el nombre del archivo y/o directorio vacío

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega ese comentario en la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *archivos vacíos*?

Comment: **Archivos vacíos = archivos que tienen size = 0 cuando se ejecuta el comando ls -l**

Comment: Prueba con `find -empty -printf '%f\n'` y comenta el resultado

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras, el comando funciona perfecto...

Answer (score 0):

Al omitir el nombre del directorio, el comando ls –a muestra el contenido del directorio donde se encuentra.

Espero que les sirva, saludos.

Comment: Te agradezco, pero no es la respuesta que busco, necesito mostrar en pantalla los archivos y directorios vacíos del directorio actual, mostrando solo el nombre del archivo o directorio y no la ruta completa (puedo usar el comando **find**)